# MERN app in microk8s kubernetes with ingress, page does not display

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I have a Mongo, Express, React Node app that is currently deployed in a microk8s pod. I am trying to setup Ingress for the app. The express server is setup to serve the react with express.static like below

```
  app.use(express.static('DemoApp/build'));

  app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'DemoApp', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

Everything works fine when I navigate to the ip:port of the kubernetes cluster and even everything works fine when I navigate to the FQDN for the ingress host but as soon as I add a path to the ingress then the app only shows a white screen. One note, my kubernetes node and workstations are all running inside an internal private network. I am not trying to expose anything outside of that. I have tried to follow the step provided in this post ([ReactJS app displays whitescreen using Kubernetes Ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383104/reactjs-app-displays-whitescreen-using-kubernetes-ingress)) but it has not fixed the issue. I have the built in ingress controller enabled for microk8s.

Below is the YAML I am using for ingress that doesnt work

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: apps.sst.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /demo(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: mern-demo
          servicePort: 4000
```

Here is the YAML for ingress that does work

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  annotations:
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: apps.sst.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path:
        backend:
          serviceName: mern-demo
          servicePort: 4000
```

One other note is that my app is using react router. Based on further research I am wondering if this affects things at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you connecting to Ingress? How did you deploy `Nginx Ingress` I assume you did it as you are using `rewrite` which is not supported by default `Ingress`? Did you try to add second annotatin `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`? If you would like to connect to the ingres from outside of the cluster (browser, etc) you should use `http://127.0.0.1/mern-demo`

Comment: I deployed Ingress by using the command microk8s enable ingress. When I check microk8s status I see that ingress is enabled. Is there something more that I need to do besides that in the built-in microk8s ingress to enable rewrite? I have bind9 setup on my server with a A name that points to my node ip address with apps.sst.com. If I dont add any paths to the ingress configuration. I can navigate to apps.sst.com from an external workstation and I get the react app. I have now also tried adding "homepage": "." to the package.json for my react app but that didnt change anything.

Comment: I will try adding that second annotation and see if that changes anything

Comment: No change from adding the second annotation. If I try to go to apps.sst.com/demo on my external workstation (on the same private network) I get and error in the browser console: GET http://apps.sst.com/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rewrite-target](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) annotation which was used in your YAML

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

**works only for [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)**. As you are using your default `ingress` it will not work. You would need to install it manually as it is mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

Now depends on your env if it's local or cloud you would need to configure [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/). For more details you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110876/kubernetes-service-external-ip-pending).

There was also similar StackOverflow question regarding `Nginx Ingress` issue on `MicroK8s`, you can read about it in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917095/microk8s-ingress-ingressed-service-always-resolves-to-127-0-0-1-and-not-pod-i).

However, do you need to use rewrite? You cannot use `multiple paths` and `default backend`? Something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: hello-world
    servicePort: 60000
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /world
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-world
          servicePort: 60000
      - path: /kube
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: I tried it without rewrite and was getting the same white page. I did however fix the issue by using the mircok8s built in ambassador ingress. For some reason that worked fine as long as I specified the homepage in the package.json for the react client.

Comment: I am actually still having one problem with my ingress setup. If I refresh the page then the app will not reload because it defaults back to the root path without the ingress path appended to the URL. I have tried declaring basename="/ingresspath" in the BrowserRouter tag for react router but that doesn't seem to have any effect.